# PHP website and Android application using parse.com server

Tags: php, android, parse-platform

Is it possible to create an Android application and Website using PHP with a common database in the Parse.com server?

Suggest me related to the parse server itself because I have already created an Android Application using parse server. Now I need to create a back-end web application as an admin website to manage the mobile application user's data. Since I am familiar with PHP it would be easy for me.

Comment: Yes, look at their PHP sdk.

Comment: Ya i gone through that, but i don't know how to deploy things from the basic. Can you suggest me any link if possible.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate a REST api?

Comment: That's what parse is using, you would have to learn how to integrate that. There are tons of tutorials for integrating REST with php web applications